# SIGFPE при подключении порта к конференции

Tags: c, pjsip

Создаю биндинги для передачи аудио-данных.

```
#include <pjsua-lib/pjsua.h>
#include <pjsua-lib/pjsua_internal.h>
#include <pjmedia/port.h>
#include <pjmedia/errno.h>
#include <pj/assert.h>
#include <pj/pool.h>
#include <pj/string.h>

#define SIGNATURE PJMEDIA_SIG_CLASS_PORT_AUD('C','B')

struct callback_port {
    pjmedia_port base;
};

extern void C_put_frame(int, void*, pj_size_t);
extern pj_status_t C_get_frame(int, void*, pj_size_t);

static void init_conference() {
    pjsua_var.media_cfg.clock_rate = 48000;
    pjsua_var.mconf_cfg.channel_count = 2;
    pjsua_var.mconf_cfg.bits_per_sample = 16;
    pjsua_var.mconf_cfg.samples_per_frame = pjsua_var.media_cfg.clock_rate * pjsua_var.mconf_cfg.channel_count * pjsua_var.media_cfg.audio_frame_ptime / 1000;
    unsigned opt = 0;
    opt = PJMEDIA_CONF_NO_DEVICE;
    if (pjsua_var.media_cfg.quality >= 3 && pjsua_var.media_cfg.quality <= 4) {
        opt |= PJMEDIA_CONF_SMALL_FILTER;
    } else if (pjsua_var.media_cfg.quality < 3) {
        opt |= PJMEDIA_CONF_USE_LINEAR;
        }
    pj_status_t status = pjmedia_conf_create(pjsua_var.pool,
                pjsua_var.media_cfg.max_media_ports,
                pjsua_var.media_cfg.clock_rate,
                pjsua_var.mconf_cfg.channel_count,
                pjsua_var.mconf_cfg.samples_per_frame,
                pjsua_var.mconf_cfg.bits_per_sample,
                opt, &pjsua_var.mconf);
}

static pj_status_t callback_port_put_frame(pjmedia_port *this_port, pjmedia_frame *frame) {
    const struct callback_port *port;
    PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(this_port->info.signature == SIGNATURE, PJ_EINVALIDOP);

    port = (struct callback_port*) this_port;
    if (frame->type == PJMEDIA_FRAME_TYPE_AUDIO) {
        C_put_frame(0, frame->buf, frame->size);
    }

    return PJ_SUCCESS;
}

static pj_status_t callback_port_get_frame(pjmedia_port *this_port, pjmedia_frame *frame) {

    PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(this_port->info.signature == SIGNATURE, PJ_EINVALIDOP);
// TODO
    return PJ_SUCCESS;
}

static pj_status_t callback_port_on_destroy(pjmedia_port *this_port) {
    PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(this_port->info.signature == SIGNATURE, PJ_EINVALIDOP);
    this_port->info.signature = 0;
    return PJ_SUCCESS;
}

static int callback_audio_device_create(unsigned *rrec_id, unsigned *rslot) {
    if (pjsua_var.rec_cnt >= PJ_ARRAY_SIZE(pjsua_var.recorder)) {
        return PJ_ETOOMANY;
    }
    unsigned rec_id, slot;
    PJSUA_LOCK();
    for (rec_id = 0; rec_id < PJ_ARRAY_SIZE(pjsua_var.recorder); ++rec_id) {
    if (pjsua_var.recorder[rec_id].port == NULL) {
        break;
        }
    }
    pj_pool_t *pool = pjsua_pool_create("callback-audio", 512, 512);
    if (!pool) {
        PJSUA_UNLOCK();
        return PJ_ENOMEM;
    }
    struct callback_port *port;
    port = PJ_POOL_ZALLOC_T(pool, struct callback_port);
    if (port == NULL) {
        PJSUA_UNLOCK();
        return PJ_ENOMEM;
    }
    const pj_str_t name = pj_str("callback-port");
    pjmedia_port_info_init(
        &port->base.info,
        &name,
        SIGNATURE,
    pjsua_var.media_cfg.clock_rate,
    pjsua_var.mconf_cfg.channel_count,
        pjsua_var.mconf_cfg.samples_per_frame,
    pjsua_var.mconf_cfg.bits_per_sample
    );
    port->base.on_destroy = &callback_port_on_destroy;
    port->base.put_frame = &callback_port_put_frame;
    port->base.get_frame = &callback_port_get_frame;
    pj_status_t status = pjmedia_conf_add_port(pjsua_var.mconf, pool, &port->base, &name, &slot); // <- SIGFPE
    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) {
    pjmedia_port_destroy(&port->base);
    PJSUA_UNLOCK();
        return status;
    }
    pjsua_var.recorder[rec_id].port = &port->base;
    pjsua_var.recorder[rec_id].slot = slot;
    pjsua_var.recorder[rec_id].pool = pool;
    pjsua_var.rec_cnt++;
    PJSUA_UNLOCK();
    *rrec_id = rec_id;
    *rslot = slot;
    return PJ_SUCCESS;
}

static void callback_audio_device_destroy(unsigned id) {
    PJSUA_LOCK();
    if (pjsua_var.recorder[id].port) {
        pjsua_conf_remove_port(pjsua_var.recorder[id].slot);
        pjmedia_port_destroy(pjsua_var.recorder[id].port);
        pjsua_var.recorder[id].port = NULL;
        pjsua_var.recorder[id].slot = 0xFFFF;
        pj_pool_release(pjsua_var.recorder[id].pool);
        pjsua_var.recorder[id].pool = NULL;
        pjsua_var.rec_cnt--;
    }
    PJSUA_UNLOCK();
}
```

При вызове `pjmedia_conf_add_port` вылетает `fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal SIGFPE: floating-point exception code=0x1 addr=0x7f466bd37f32 pc=0x7f466bd37f32]`. Это  происходит только если я ставлю **семплрейт выше 16kHz и более одного канала**.

Задача: получать и отправлять PCM-данные звонка **в два канала и частотой 48kHz**, использую калбеки.

Что я делаю не так? Вывод gdb

```
Thread 22 "call_bot" received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffd0ff9700 (LWP 39156)]
0x00007ffff7b98f32 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpjmedia.so.2
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7b98f32 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpjmedia.so.2
#1  0x00007ffff7b9a62e in pjmedia_conf_add_port () from /usr/lib/libpjmedia.so.2
#2  0x000000000083e931 in callback_audio_device_create (rslot=0xc000308b94, rrec_id=0xc000308b90) at /home/zabqer/0/sip/callback_audio_device.c:121
#3  _cgo_eb4dc7f96a71_Cfunc_callback_audio_device_create (v=0xc00042dcd8) at cgo-gcc-prolog:54
```

Answer (score 1):

SIGFPE означает, что при попытке выполнить арифметическую операцию из памяти был получен недопустимый аргумент. Там много разных вариантов (зависит от платформы), если вам нужна конкретная причина - сделайте перехват сигнала и посмотрите значение 
SA_SIGINFO.

Но это вряд-ли Вам поможет в решении проблемы. Скорее всего, проблема в том, что когда Вы передаёте библиотечной функции (какой-то) из pjsua буфер (frame->buf) для обработки, то этот буфер либо вообще пустой, либо в нём всякий мусор, числами с не являющийся.

Вы ведь запускаете программу под отладчиком? Ну так в чём проблема?! Скомпиллируйте её с ключом -g и когда она упадёт, введите команду отладчика *bt*. Отладчик покажет Вам место, где произошла ошибка.

Comment: До передачи буферов вообще не доходит. Проблема вот тут https://github.com/chakrit/pjsip/blob/b0af6c8fc8ed97bb03d3afa4ab42c24f46a9212b/pjmedia/src/pjmedia/conference.c#L369. `port_ptime` равен нулю, что очень странно.  Проблема частично решается добавлением кода `if (conf_port->samples_per_frame == 15)
                conf_port->samples_per_frame = afd->clock_rate * afd->channel_count * afd->frame_time_usec / 1000;` после 369й строчки. Но не каждый же раз патчить библиотеку

Comment: Если проблема в 369 строке, то основной подозреваемый *port_ptime* ( == 0?).  Значение ему присваивается в строке 351. Тогда начинаем подозревать  *conf_port->samples_per_frame* - смотрим строки 292 и 297.  Значение берётся из *conf->samples_per_frame* - там что? Оказывается, это поле в структуре *pjmedia_conf*, которая является параметром *create_conf_port(...)*. Вот и смотрите, что вы туда передаёте.

Comment: Значение `conf_port->samples_per_frame ` присваивается на строке 292 `PJMEDIA_AFD_SPF` (https://github.com/chakrit/pjsip/blob/b0af6c8fc8ed97bb03d3afa4ab42c24f46a9212b/pjmedia/include/pjmedia/format.h#L539) значения берутся из `pjmedia_audio_format_detail` (https://github.com/chakrit/pjsip/blob/b0af6c8fc8ed97bb03d3afa4ab42c24f46a9212b/pjmedia/src/pjmedia/port.c#L33) который инициализируется в `pjmedia_port_info_init`, эту функцию я уже и вызываю с нужным мне семплрейтом в 48kHz

Comment: Вот и надо проверить всю эту цепочку. Ведь чудес не бывает - так? :-)